# How to keep form data in NGINX redirect?

Tags: python, nginx

I have a flask server and nginx handling the incoming connections. When I call a specific method of the flask api using https it works fine, the problem is when nginx redirects from http to https and the data included in the python call gets lost.

NGINX config file:

```
server {
    server_name myurl.com;
    listen 80;

    location / {
        return 301 https://myurl.com$request_uri;
    }
}

server {
    server_name myurl.com;
    listen 443 ssl;

    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000";

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/myurl.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/myurl.com/privkey.pem;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass flask_server:5555;
    }
}
```

Python call:

```
from requests import get

token = {'token': 'thetoken1234'}
data={'kms': '80000'}
response = get('http://myurl.com/evaluate_car', headers=token, data=data).json()
```

Calling the https version of the url works fine but in the http case the "kms" variable in the data dictionary is getting lost.

What I need to include in the NGINX config file to keep this data dictionary?

Comment: Do you really mean to use `GET` as method? Passing data is usually done through `PUT`

Comment: Is a get request with input parameters and is already working with https

Comment: point is that in a get request with form-encoded, as your `get(…, data=data)` causes, the data is part of the URL – and you're *specifically* overwriting that URL with your redirect, so this is all correct from my perspective. Easy solution: don't use GET for something which is usually done using PUT.

Comment: By the way, redirecting to HTTPS is useless in this scenario. You're not stopping your clients from sending the unencrypted data with a redirect. You simply mustn't even offer the endpoints under HTTP.

Comment: Thats right. The best option should be to delete the http option.

Comment: But I'm not sending data to a server. The data inside the data form is just a plate (of a car) and the kilometers to retrieve the specific information from the database. No sensitive data involved and after the redirect the returned data will be encrypted. I can include this data in the headers too.... But as i said I think I'll remove the http option.

Comment: @MarcusMüller+ not really. A _browser_ submitting form data puts it in the URL query part for GET or the body for POST (and never uses PUT), but that rule doesn't apply to other HTTP usage such as an API, and python `requests` _always_ puts `data=` in the body and `params=` in the query regardless of method. And `requests` does seem to drop the body on a redirect, while _if_ you used `params` to put it in query then the posted nginx config using `$request_uri` retains (copies) it in the redirect URL as desired. OTOH I concur removing http entirely is better.